# How can I guarantee USB wlan0/wlan1 order?

Tags: linux, wifi, usb, raspberry-pi, wlan

From doing research, I think I understand that the order of `wlan0` and `wlan1` ( and so on ) is determined by the order that the USB devices are recognized.

My question is whether or not this order is deterministic;  once plugged in and recognized in a specific order, will two or more adapters continue to be recognized in that order in subsequent reboots?  If not, is there a way to influence that order to become deterministic?